# Looping through a string in C gives Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

For the code below, I am getting the

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

error message, can someone help me please?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){

    char s[] = "helloWorld";


    int i;
    for(i = 1; i < strlen(s); i++)
    {
        printf("Letter is %s\n", s[i]);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Not the cause of your segfault, but arrays in C are zero based. Your loop should start with i = 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
printf("Letter is %s\n", s[i]);
```

is wrong, `%s` expects a `const char *`, and you're giving it a `char`. Change this line to

```
printf("Letter is %c\n", s[i]);
```

since the `%c` format specifier is intended for printing individual characters.

Also, in C, arrays are zero-based, so you should initialize `i` to zero using `i = 0;` as well.

Answer (score 2):

You are printing character by character so use `%c` instead of `%s`.

`%s` expects a string but `s[i]` is actually a char.

Also every time you are calling `strlen(s)`. And `strlen` is not changing , so better to use one variable for it and call only once before entering into loop.

A more optimized way like this :

```
int len=strlen(s);
for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        printf("Letter is %c\n", s[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Good point about that optimization, but most likely the compiler will make it anyway.

Comment: @H2CO3 : Yeah , but It's better to follow good programming technique.

Comment: Also, if you're compiling with gcc, you will see a warning when using the wrong printf format: seg.c:13:9: warning: format ‘%s’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’   With such a warning, you know a segfault will happen.